# Type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, namespaces

I'm trying to build my first ASP.NET Web Forms project but I'm facing some serious problem.
I created two project files in my project named: BLL and DAL.
I created classes named `class.cs` and `class1.cs` in both the above files respectively. When I add `using System.Data;` in any of the `.cs` files, it displays the following errors:

1: `Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) DAL..NET Platform 5.4`
2. `Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) BLL..NET Platform 5.4`

I tried adding assembly references by right click on references -> Add reference -> Checking `System.Data` and rebuilding it again but it didn't help me.

When I hover mouse over `using System.Data;` it displays the following thing:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to target .NET Core - which is a bad idea if you're actually trying to do web-forms, as I don't believe web forms are part of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't what exactly was happening, but when I created a new project targeting to .NET framework 4.0 rather than 4.5 it helped me and my problem got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

First when you hover your "**System.Data**" it shows a message, which is pretty much straight forward to understand that you haven't used any classes of System.Data. When you implement those classes, this message will disappear.

Second, You got an error -

> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   DAL..NET Platform 5.4

So basically you have to have an assembly refernce of System.Data into your project.

Go to References and check whether System.Data Assembly exist or not. If not then install it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried all this, but it didn't helped me. I solved this by downgrading my .net Framework from 4.5 to 4.0, this helped me solving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are simply missing the "System.Data" reference.

In Solutions Explorer window right click on the 'Reference' entry ->  Press Add Reference  -> click on Assemblies > Search for 'System.Data'  ->  press the check box ( I always forget this step.) ->  press OK.

Answer (score 0):

your namespace and class name is same,

rename your class name.